# Is there a way to see the actual error message in AWS X-Ray instead of State?

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-step-functions, aws-xray

I have enabled X-Ray for my StepFunction state machine, and in X-Ray trace map, I can see in the Subsegment section, I can locate which step in the statefunction has caught an error, but it only says `States.TaskFailed` but with no actual error message: (screenshot shown below)

[image]

However, if I navigate to stepfunction execution event history, I can locate in 'TashStateExited', and I see something like:

```
 "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "output": {
    "Error": "States.TaskFailed",
    "Cause": xxxxxxxxxxx (the actual error message)
```

I wonder if there is a way that I can see this error message directly in X-Ray without navigating to the specific execution event history? Since X-Ray is supposed to make monitoring easier and help us debug, how come it's not showing the actual error message in trace map?

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to do this manually by running my code in a try/except block which traps the error and then using a `subsegment.addError()` call to add the exception information to the trace segment before re-throwing the exception.  I'm not sure of a way to get X-Ray to do that automatically... here's a thread on the AWS forums that provides a bit of background: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=282800&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Step Function sends all the collected Errors and Causes to X-Ray. But they may not appear in the subsegment for the state but in the one for task.

1- In X-Ray, check "Raw data" tab of the trace. Does the error appear in the JSON there?

2- In the Timeline tab you should be able to see the error under the task:

This is the state subsegment:

[image: State subsegment]

And this is the task subsegment:

[image: Task subsegment]

If you can't still find the error in X-Ray, please post the state machine definition and the Raw trace JSON.